# Global vuex watchers

Tags: vue.js, vuex, watch

I have a Vuex store feeding many Vue components in a somewhat large web app. I would like to be able to watch Vuex states or getters for logging purposes. However, I want to be able to watch them 'globally', i.e. without relying on any particular Vue component. This rules out tricks like

```
//aComponent.vue
watch:{ '$store.state.data'(value, oldValue) { /*do something here*/ }}
```

and

```
//App.vue
created() {
  this.$store.watch((state) => state.watchedState) => {/*do something here*/ })
}
```

Instead, I am looking for a way to watch my Vuex states or getters directly from the module where the store is defined, so that whenever a state changes, I can call a function passing it as arguments the old state and the new state, so as to write the change into a database (ideally the change itself would be detected automatically, as in Vue's `watch(new,old) {...}`.

I suppose I should use Vuex native method `store.watch()` for this purpose. But so far I have not be able to invoke it from the store module, as desired.

Any clue? Or did I miss something and what I am trying to do would be just as efficiently done with a different technique?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For watching mutations you have this options.

You can `subscribe` to a store and get notified by mutation after it happens.

> store.subscribe( (mutation, state) => {
>   })

You can achieve this in a couple of ways:

1. use `subscribe` on the store you create by hand, most likely in `main.js`
2. create a plugin that gets appended to each instance of a store and again `subscribe` to it
3. just use the vuex official [plugin](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/plugins.html#built-in-logger-plugin) for logging

For watching getters you probably need to monkey patch the `getters` property by hand.

Then again, if you want to watch what happens with vuex during development you can use [vuejs tools](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools)

Comment: Thanks very much for the subscribe hint, this is going to be useful!
Besides, how would you go about monkey coding the getters to get the change proper, and not simply the new state (i.e. how to protect the old state from overwrite in the context of a getter)? Not sure how that would work. Is there really not way of using something like
`store.watch(
      (state, getters) => getters.status,
      (newValue, oldValue) => { `
from within a store module?